# How to append the new results of DF to the old output file (with Datetime)

Tags: python, pyspark

I create a DF and use it for live reporting but the project I'm working on have requested a separate copy of it is saved for historical reporting down the track.

The final dataframe is built every week (and overwritten) so I want to take a copy of it when its build and append it the previous builds data with the current datetimestamp

To be honest I have no idea where to start with this one.

```
    df = my_input

    #add a datetime column
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    type(timestamp)

    df = df.withColumn('build_time', unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))

    # df = df.append()
    my_output.write_dataframe(
        df.union(my_output.dataframe())
    )
```

```
Original DF
+---+-----+
|age|name |
+---+-----+
|1  |Alice|
|2  |Bob  |
+---+-----+

New file
Week 1
+---+-----+---------------------+
|age|name |time                 |
+---+-----+---------------------+
|1  |Alice|2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Bob  |2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
+---+-----+---------------------+

Week 2
+---+-----+---------------------+
|age|name |time                 |
+---+-----+---------------------+
|1  |Alice|2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Bob  |2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
|1  |Alice|2017-08-09 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Bob  |2017-08-09 16:16:14.0|
+---+-----+---------------------+

Week 3
+---+-----+---------------------+
|age|name |time                 |
+---+-----+---------------------+
|1  |Alice|2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Bob  |2017-08-02 16:16:14.0|
|1  |Alice|2017-08-09 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Bob  |2017-08-09 16:16:14.0|
|1  |Alice|2017-08-16 16:16:14.0|
|2  |Bob  |2017-08-16 16:16:14.0|
+---+-----+---------------------+
```

Any help most appreciated

Comment: You can try mode='append' when writing your historical output. The new data for the week will be added to the history for previous weeks. [writer docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter)

Comment: Thanks Hitobat the actual code I needed was

`my_output.set_mode('modify')
    my_output.write_dataframe(df_with_dt)`